# What is the correct onliner for a column filter expression using Perl?

Tags: bash, perl, command-line

I try to filter expression from a configuration file under Linux mixing bash command line tools and Perl commands in a pipe.

I have a configuration file (see section configuration) and can filter the relevant lines by using  `

```sh
grep PG.DATABASE database.conf | \
sed -r -e 's/^\s*//;s/\s+/ /'  | \
cut -d ' ' -f2 | \
sort
```

And get the result as expected:

```
DB.GRM.CON.LOCAL.V01
DB.GRM.CON.LOCAL.V02
DB.GRM.CON.LOCAL.V03
```

Now I want to switch to Perl

```sh
grep PG.DATABASE database.conf | \
perl -lpe 's/^\s*//; @m = split /\s+/; print $m[1]'
```

but I get strange results with a duplication of the input line.

```
DB.GRM.CON.LOCAL.V01
PG.DATABASE: DB.GRM.CON.LOCAL.V01 BEGIN
DB.GRM.CON.LOCAL.V02
PG.DATABASE: DB.GRM.CON.LOCAL.V02 BEGIN
DB.GRM.CON.LOCAL.V03
PG.DATABASE: DB.GRM.CON.LOCAL.V03 BEGIN
```

### Question

Why is the duplication there and is the correct Perl oneliner for result achieved with the command line tools?

### Configuration File

```
PG.CONFIG: DEFAULT BEGIN

   # Green Rebel Database via PG.SERVICE ------------------------
   PG.DATABASE: DB.GRM.CON.LOCAL.V01 BEGIN
     SERVICE:     'LOC-GRM-V0'
   END.DB.GRM.CON.LOCAL.V01

   # Green Rebel Database via DBI Driver ------------------------
   PG.DATABASE: DB.GRM.CON.LOCAL.V02 BEGIN
     DBI.PG: "dbi:Pg:dbname=grm;host=localhost;port=5432"
     AUTO.COMMIT: FALSE
     RAISE.ERROR: TRUE
     PRINT.ERROR: FALSE
   END.DB.GRM.CON.LOCAL.V02

   # Green Rebel Database via Host, Db, User, Pass --------------
   PG.DATABASE: DB.GRM.CON.LOCAL.V03 BEGIN
     SERVER:     'localhost'
     PORT:        5432
     DATABASE:    'grm'
     USER:        ${/SYSTEM/USER}
     SSL.MODE:    allow
     AUTO.COMMIT: FALSE
     RAISE.ERROR: TRUE
     PRINT.ERROR: FALSE
   END.DB.GRM.CON.LOCAL.V03
END.DEFAULT
```

Comment: Try following oneliner `perl -nE '/PG.DATABASE: (\S+)/ && say $1' database.conf`

Comment: You could use `grep PG.DATABASE db_grm.cnf | cut -d' ' -f5` as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest changing the `-p` option (which makes it automatically print every line) to `-n`. You can also skip the `grep` and let `perl` do it:

```
perl -lne 'if(/PG\.DATABASE/) {chomp; s/^\s*//; @m = split /\s+/; print $m[1]}' database.conf
```

A simplification could be:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if(/PG\.DATABASE:\s(\S+)/)'  database.conf
```

Comment: Yes that's brilliant, but  guess `^\s*` has to be placed into the regex `/^\s*PG\.DATABASE: (\S+)/`

Comment: @huckfinn I noticed that the line doesn't start with `PG.DATABASE:` so I removed the `^` which makes it match it anywhere on the line so `^\s*` will not be necessary.

Comment: You don't need to chomp or strip leading whitespace if you split normally on `' '` instead of `\s+`. The `-a` switch replaces all of that code. The simplification is a better solution, though.

Comment: @TLP Thanks. I made the top one to show OP how it would fix the code OP had when asking the question with little changes, but I agree that the simplification is the preferable of the two. I like @Fravadona's version with the `-a` switch too. Really neat.

Answer (score 4):

You can also let perl do the splitting into columns automatically, that might be the *correct way* to filter *columns* in perl:

```sh
perl -lane 'print $F[1] if $F[0] eq "PG.DATABASE:"' database.conf
```

```
DB.GRM.CON.LOCAL.V01
DB.GRM.CON.LOCAL.V02
DB.GRM.CON.LOCAL.V03
```

But your format isn't really column oriented so I would go with a regex capture solution like in the other answers:

```sh
perl -lne 'print $1 if(/^\s*PG\.DATABASE:\s*(\S+)/)' database.conf
```

Comment: OK, also brilliant and short. Why is there an empty line before the first match?

Comment: Not sure, I don't get any empty line with the example `database.conf`; you may have a `PG.DATABASE:` without value in your conf file?

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```
perl -nE 'say $1 if /^\s+PG\.DATABASE:\s+(\S+)/' file
```

Which also works in GNU grep:

```
grep -oP '^\s+PG\.DATABASE:\s+\K\S+' file
```

And GNU sed:

```
sed -nE 's/^\s+PG\.DATABASE:\s+(\S+).*/\1/p' file
```

Or POSIX sed:

```
sed -nE 's/^[[:blank:]]*PG\.DATABASE:[[:blank:]]*([^[:blank:]]*).*/\1/p' file
```